# Что содержит boot.img, и как он загружается

Tags: android, kernel

Решил разобраться как работает Android, застрял на понимании `boot.img`.

- Что он содержит?
- Что загрузчик загружает в нем?

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/partitions-images

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, это и все? А точнее? И второй вопрос.

Comment: Да я просто погуглил. А в андроиде ваще не шарю ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, так и думал :D

Comment: Для какой архитектуры? У Intel и ARM — разные данные и разное загружается первой стадией загрузчика. А вообще в исходниках есть _bootheader.h_, в котором в комментариях всё написано. Ну и миллион сайтов с разными проектами и открытыми исходниками на тему собрать и разобрать.